# Show comma instead of point as decimal separator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, type-conversion, currency

I just want to get the right number format here in germany, so i need to show commas as decimal separator instead of points. But this...

```
DECLARE @euros money
SET @euros = 1025040.2365
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(30), @euros, 1)
```

Displays `1,025,040.24` instead of `1.025.040,24` (or `1025040,24`). In C# it would be simple to provide the appropriate `CultureInfo` but how to do it in T-SQL?

Do i really need to use `REPLACE`? But even if, how to replace `1,025,040.24` correctly?

Comment: formatting is a display property, why would you ever want to do this in SQL?

Comment: What is the expected result for value '1,025,040.24', do you think?

Comment: @Jamiec: because it's a view. But you're right, it could be done in the client application. But in this case i want to control everything from database.

Comment: @PankajExplorer - most cultures that use `.` for the thousand separator use the `,` as the decimal separator (yes, the exact opposite)

Comment: i run your query in my DB it's return me 1,025,040.24 why ?

Comment: Looks like REPLACE is your option in 2005. From 2012 you have the FORMAT() function. Why does it matter the format in SQL? What is consuming the results of the query?

Comment: @Juan: i want to control output completely in the view, so that i don't have to change any client applications that access this view. It's a web application but also excel, maybe other applications in near future.

Comment: Because @tinka, you SQL Server has culture settting with `,` as tousand separator and `.` as decimal.

Comment: Moderator nominations are on.  Have you considered being a moderator?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, as far as I know, there are no culture-specific options for convert available.

So you can do it using replaces (yes, it looks a bit ugly...)

```
select 
    replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(30), @euros, 1), ',', '|'), '.', ','), '|', '.')
```

Idea: first change comma to something, then change dot to comma, and then "something" back to dot.

Comment: Yep, chain of `REPLACE`s is about the best you can do.

Comment: tim query is working fine for my DB it's giving me 1,025,040.24 without doing anything why ?

Comment: @tinka: i don't want english format i want german(and others)  which is `1.025.040,24`

Comment: @tinka - presumably because your default language already formats the value as `1.025.040,24`. This solution *swap* dots and commas, but what value you get from the original `CONVERT` from `money` depends on your language settings. E.g. add `SET Language german` above the code in the original question and you get the desired result. But you can't save language settings in a view definition and many server setups have everyone use US English settings for... other reasons.

Comment: Seems to do the job. Thank you. I will make it a scalar valued function, i don't want to see this weird sql in my queries.

Comment: IN SQL Server 2017+ you could use a single "TRANSLATE" instead of two REPLACE.

Answer (score 39):

To provide the appropriate culture info, in SQL 2012 there is the `FORMAT()` function. Here's an example:

```
declare @f float = 123456.789;

select
  [raw]      = str(@f,20,3)
 ,[standard] = cast(format(@f, 'N', 'en-US') as varchar(20))
 ,[German] = cast(format(@f, 'N', 'de-DE') as varchar(20))
```

returns

```
raw                  |standard   |German     |
---------------------|-----------|-----------|
          123456.789 |123,456.79 |123.456,79 |
```

You can also specify in the second parameter a custom format string with the same rules as for .NET.

Docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: Please note that 'de-de' is German, not European :) 

Other countries in Europe have other ways of formatting numbers.

Best, Mr. Nitpicker

Comment: @TorkilJohnsen you're right, even though the meaning was clear. I updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @euros money
SET @euros = 1025040.2365
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(30), @euros, 0), '.', ',')
```

should do it (at least to get `1025040,24`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `replace` something like this:

```
DECLARE @euros money 
SET @euros = 1025040.2365

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(30), @euros, 1),',',''),'.',',');
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1686/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace thousand separator comma(,) to a Zero length string (''), and then you can replace Decimal('.') to comma(',') in the same select statement.