# Change thousands seperator from comma to point

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table on which I query logistics costs. 
The `sqlfiddle` with the table you can find [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bd97a/4):

To query the Costs_Outbound I use the following SQL:

```
SELECT country,
FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 2) as Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

All this works fine so far.

---

Now, I want to change the thousands seperator from `","` to `"."`. 
Therefore, I tried to somehow go with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611221/show-comma-instead-of-point-as-decimal-separator):

```
SELECT country,
REPLACE(FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 2),",",".") as Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

However, I could not make it work so far. 
Do you have any idea where there is a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function `FORMAT(number,2 ,'de_DE' )`

```
SELECT country,
FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 2 ,'de_DE') Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bd97a/14

Comment: Perfect. Exaclty what I was looking for. I also updated it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bd97a/16

Comment: @Michi if it helps please accept my answer with upvote  as a SO appreciation

Answer (score 0):

Try this: just replace double quote with single quote

```
SELECT country,
REPLACE(FORMAT(sum(Costs_Outbound), 2),',','.') as Costs_Outbound
FROM Logistics
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thanks man. It works really nice. The only issue I face now is that the decimal seperator is also converted to a point. However, I would like to have it as a comma. Do you have any idea how to solve this?