# Decimal not displayed with current locale in query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a SqlServer 2012 database, with Italian locale setup, and I have a weird behaviour in results I get in SSMS when querying a decimal field

For other numeric format (e.g money or float) the query display as result a number with Italian decimal separator (comma ",")

for decimal, the international decimal separator is used (dot ".")

Here an example:

```
select 
    cast(1234.567 as decimal(7, 3)) as decimalValue
    , cast(1234.567 as float) as floatValue
    , cast(1234.567 as money) as MoneyValue
```

Result:

```
decimalValue    floatValue  MoneyValue
1234.567        1234,567    1234,567
```

Actually I'm querying a decimal field of a table, but the above query result is the same

How to get the decimal value formatted with Italian decimal separator in query results from SSMS?
What I need is to copy and paste results in an Excel file (again, setup with Italian locale), and the decimal values formatted with "." are recognized as text and not as number when pasting in Excel

**EDIT**:
Just found a workaround:

```
select cast(MyDecimalField as float) from MyTable
```

This seems to do the trick, but it's weird that I need to cast from a "precise" numeric type to float numeric type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `FORMAT` function, which was introduced in 2012.

Some examples here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41358670/78522
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I ended using your solution, which I think is a workaround anyway; I prefer this instead of using `cast as float`
The question remains: why SQLServer has a different default format for decimal and other numeric formats?: