# What is the best approach?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2019

At work we have a SQL Server 2019 instance. There are two big tables in the same database that have to be joined to obtain specific data: one contains GPS data taken at 4 minutes interval, but there could be in between records as well. The important thing here is that there is a non-key attribute called `file_id`, a timestamp (`DATE_TIME` column), latitude and longitude. The other attributes are not relevant, and the key is autogenerated (`identity` column), so it's of no use to me.

The other table contains transaction records that have among other attributes a timestamp (`FECHATRX` column), and the same non-key file ID attribute the GPS table has, and also an autogenerated key with no relation at all with the other key.

For each file ID there are several records in both tables that have to be somewhat joined in order to obtain for a given file ID and transaction record both its latitude and longitude. The tables aren't ordered at all.

My idea is to pair records of the same file ID and I imagine it to be this way (I haven't done it yet because it was explained to me earlier today):

1. Order both tables by file ID and timestamp
2. For the same file ID all the transaction table records who have a timestamp equal or greater than the first timestamp from the GPS table and lower than the following timestamp from the same GPS table will be given both latitude and longitude values from that first record, for they are considered to belong to that latitude-longitude pair (actually they probably are somewhere in the middle, but this is an assumption and everybody agrees with this)
3. When a transaction record has a timestamp equal or greater than the second timestamp, then the third timestamp will act as an end point, all the records in between from the transaction table will obtain the same coordinates from the second record until one timestamp equals or be greater than the third, and so on until a new file ID is reached or there are no records left in one or both tables.

To me this sounds like nested cursors and several variables to save the first GPS record's values while we are also saving the second GPS record's timestamp for comparison purposes, and of course the file ID itself as a control variable, but is this the best way to obtain the latitude / longitude data for each and every transaction record from the GPS table?

Are other approaches better than using nested cursors?

As I said I haven't done anything yet, the only thing I can do is to show you some data from both tables, I just wanted to know if there is another (and simpler) way of doing this than using nested cursors.

Thank you.
Alejandro

Comment: It will be easier for others to help if you can include some sample data and the execpected result as formatted text (no image please)

Answer (score 0):

No need to reorder tables or use a complex cursor loop. A properly constructed index can provide an efficient join, and a `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER_APPLY` can be used to handle the complex "select closest prior GPS coordinate" lookup logic.

Assuming your table structure is something like:

- GPS(gps_id, file_id, timestamp, latitude, longitude, ...)
- Transaction(transaction_id, timestamp, file_id, ...)

First create an index on the GPS table to allow efficient lookup by file_id and timestamp.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_GPS_FileId_Timestamp
    ON GPS(file_id, timestamp)
    INCLUDE(latitude, longitude)
```

The INCLUDE clause is optional, but it allows the index to serve up lat/long without the need to access the primary table.

You can then use a query something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transaction T
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM GPS G
    WHERE G.file_id = T.file_id
    AND G.timestamp <= T.timestamp
    ORDER BY G.timestamp DESC
) G1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM GPS G
    WHERE G.file_id = T.file_id
    AND G.timestamp >= T.timestamp
    ORDER BY G.timestamp
) G2
```

`CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` are like `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`, but have more flexibility to define a subquery with complex conditions to handle cases like this.

The G1 subquery will efficiently select the immediately prior or equal GPS timestamp record with the same file_id. G2 does the same for equal or immediately following. Per your requirements, you only need G1, but having both might give you the opportunity to interpolate between the two points or to handle cases where there is no preceding matching record.

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_pmlQ1rG) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very efficient way of solving the problem, I never used OUTER APPLY before, I will give it a closer look to fully understand how it works.

Comment: Ok, now I can see that the output is showing an 'interval': for each transaction record, we have a lower and upper timestamp, and the lower in time will be the upper timestamp and so on, which is Ok so to give a reference frame.

I've tried to insert the output into a new table, and it failed because of the repeated field names (i.e. id_registro, or the fact that the GPS table is being queried twice). If I want to keep all fields from GPS (G1 and G2) and avoid some repetitions, how can I perform the SELECT / INTO clause? If you need to see the complete output I can show it to you. Thank you!

Comment: In oher words, how can I limit the projections, by selecting fields instead of full projections with '*'? Also I'm having trouble with decimal point vs comma formatting for the latitude / longitude fields. We use comma for decimal instead of points and the output is formatted with points. Thank you!

Comment: To avoid conflicting field names, you can selectively reference and assign aliases the desired fields. `SELECT T.*, G1.timestamp AS timestamp1, G1.latitude AS latitude1, etc.`. As for comma as the decimal separator, that is usually something left to the presentation layer, but you can also look at suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611221/show-comma-instead-of-point-as-decimal-separator).

Comment: Great! Thank you for all the help on this matter!